# REST: multiple ways of creating the same resource

Tags: rest

If you are modelling a resource which can be created in multiple ways, how do you best deal with that?

I can imagine doing POST to the same resource with a query param differentiating the different ways, something like

```
POST /logins?type=pwd with body { email, pwd } -> CREATED /logins/1
POST /logins?type=token with body { token } -> CREATED /logins/2
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that a single `POST /logins` should be enough. It can be called with a payload containing `{email, pwd}` or `{token}` only. The implementation of this endpoint should decide in which case we are and how to create the resource after making the necessary validation on the body (email + pwd provided or token only provided).

Comment: I agree with this. When sending an HTTP request, you are sending in a request in a form of HTTP document. The semantics in this end point is to create a single resource. In your case, its to create "login sessions". I'd probably call this endpoint `POST /session` since your technically creating a session resource out of this. (unless login is a resource type in your nomenclature... )

Answer (score 0):

I like your idea Alex.  Darin's solution does solve the problem but...

I would like to keep my ASP.NET controller actions handling only one type of request (model binding) and avoid god methods.  I also like the idea of having 2 ways of creating (POST) an object depending on the input (Factory) and I want to rely on routing.

The issue with Alex's solution and my "requirements" is that ASP.NET routing cannot use the querystring.

For now I have settled on this:

```
POST /logins/pwd with body { email, pwd } -> CREATED /logins/1
POST /logins/token with body { token } -> CREATED /logins/2
```

I would love to hear others ideas on ways to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Query string parameters are not widely used in REST APIs, except with GET on a collection-type resource. In that situation they represent things like pagination, collection filters, search criteria... They express the expectation that only a specific part of the resource is expected as body.

With that in mind I believe both patterns are perfectly valid REST calls and aligned with the current best practices.

**An API may very well decide to support one or the other or both**.

**POST /logins without a query string**

As Darin said, the server can sort out what to do according to the fields provided (or not) in the content.
The server will validate the consistency of the body and take appropriate action.

**POST /logins?type=pwd**

This form has the obvious drawback of added complexity.

However it captures the intent of the user and clarifies what part of the resource is expected as body, with a couple advantages:

- the server can provide more relevant feedback (validation message). Consider for instance what the server should do if it receives as body {email, pwd, token} or {pwd, token}.
- it makes the type easily available to API gateways for routing, sharding or circuit-breaking for instance. Ultimately it would help with very large infrastructures.